# How To use JMeter for Database server performance testing?

Tags: database, jdbc, jmeter

I am testing the performance of the oracle 12c database using JMeter. I am totally new to JMeter. For testing I have create a .JAR file from java program. The java program uses JDBC driver to connect oracle database.

In JMeter, I have added Thread Group and inside the thread group I have added Java Request as Sampler. Am I following the right procedure?

If, my procedure is right, then also when I check the results in Table and Tree, I got an error. I have attached the snapshots of table and tree in JMeter.[JMeter Result Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZXsL.jpg) [image: JMeter Result Tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally people use [JDBC Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) and JDBC Request sampler for database load testing. See [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) for more information.

However JMeter is very flexible and your approach is also viable. In order to troubleshoot your problem:

1. First of all every time you face a problem with JMeter take a look into *jmeter.log* file, in the absolute majority of cases it contains enough information to get the idea why JMeter test has failed.
2. If your JAR doesn't contain Oracle JDBC driver you need to put the Oracle JDBC driver into [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) as well. JMeter restart will be required to pick the Oracle JDBC driver jar.
3. You can run JMeter with the debugger enabled like:

   ```
   java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8888 -jar ApacheJMeter.jar -t your_testplan.jmx
   ```

   and use your favourite IDE to connect to the machine running JMeter using port 8888, step-by-step walkthrough your code and see where the errors live. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more tips on getting to the bottom of your JMeter test failures.